# How to recognize a vector bundle?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

Given a connected topological space $E$, under which conditions is it possible to find a subspace $B$ such that $E$ can be regarded as a (rank $n$) vector bundle over $B$?

Is it possible to find the conditions and the $B$'s if one moves to the more rigid differentiable, holomorphic or algebraic setting?

What if we restrict to the case: dim $E$ = 2, dim $B$ = 1? When is a surface the total space of a line bundle?

Comment: I doubt you will find a satisfactory answer in the literature in much generality, but if $E$ is a simply-connected manifold that has $B$ (a manifold) as a deformation-retract, then it is a vector bundle under some reasonable conditions, by the minimal handle theorem -- closely related to the h-cobordism theorem.  A theorem of this sort appears in Kosinski's "Differential Topology" textbook.

Comment: Fibre-bundles are a little easier to identify.  Under "reasonable circumstances" assuming manifolds everywhere, all you need is some compactness and the map being a submersion.  This is just a careful application of the implicit function theorem.

Comment: There also is the [Soul Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soul_theorem) in Riemannian geometry

Answer (score 2):

The total space of a vector bundle is homotopy-equivalent to the base. Hence, for example,
the only connected surfaces which are total spaces of real line bundles are the plane, the annulus and the Möbius strip.

Answer (score 1):

In smooth manifolds, [Grabowski and Rotkiewicz - Higher vector bundles and multi-graded symplectic manifolds](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0702772) has a condition for when a monoid action $(\mathbb{R}^+, \cdot, 1)$ on a manifold $E$ induces a vector bundle structure where $E$ is the total space. I have a similar result in a recent paper ([Vector bundles and differential bundles in the category of smooth manifolds](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.11708)), so that a morphism $\lambda:E \to TE$ induces a vector bundle where $E$ is the total space whenever $\lambda$ satisfies some coherences and a certain pullback diagram (these are called *differential bundles* in a [tangent category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tangent+bundle+category)). The total space is obtained by splitting the idempotent $p \circ \lambda:E \to E$, where $p$ is the tangent projection (it's a consequence of the coherences on $\lambda$ that $p\circ \lambda$ is an idempotent).

I don't know of any similar results that hold for general topological vector bundles, but I would be interested in seeing them!